# How to disable the file toolbar in android studio

Tags: android-studio

Just a quick question. How do I remove/disable this tool bar in android studio ? I cant seem to find a setting to disable it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Android Studio 
Goto: **View** -> Click on **Navigation Bar** option (Keep it unchecked)

Now, Your entire bar will be hidden.

Again, Goto: **View** -> Click on **Navigation Bar** option

Now, Click on **Toolbar** option (Keep it checked)

Your window should look like this: 
[image]

Comment: @RajdeepSinghHundal  welcome bro. even I was finding solutions from last few months but got it a few minutes ago when shown your question.